# x11vnc: how to work locally on a display while other work remotely on another display

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I want my computer to act as a VNC server to a remote user, while I use it locally.

For that, I open 2 X sessions on the computer, one for me, the other for the remote user. I run x11vnc with the display number of the remote user session.

The remote user can connect to their session, and it works pretty fine, provided their session remains active on the server. When I activate my session on the server, the remote VNC Viewer shows a black screen with an active mouse pointer.

I tried using x2go, but it is really to slow for my old remote machine.

How do I solve my problem?

Comment: So, can I assume that you are using Linux?  What operating system sure would have been helpful.  If Linux, "VNC" is a pointless thing to use.  X11 can FORWARD it's screen to another device via IP address.  That means that you would use SSH to log into the box remotely and fire up whatever GUI app you want via forwarding.  That has been built into *nix since the beginning.  Is this what you want?

Comment: Sorry, yes I use Linux, Ubuntu 18.04 on both sides. And yes, that's what I want. If I understand you, I have to boot the remote machine without GUI, then ssh to the server, and then run "startx"? I try this soon and tell you about the result. Thanks!

Comment: You don't use "startx".. you aren't going to boot the entire desktop (even though there are ways to do so).  You will log in remotely and run whatever you want from the command line.  Like `xterm &` or even `firefox www.silly.com &`  It takes a little getting used to, but I wouldn't fight the battle of trying to run the desktop unless you are running a lightweight WM.  The performance is "2d game playing" amazing.. way better than VNC performance. Also.. this is what the "cool kids" do ;)

Comment: Yes I know that, but I want the remote slow machine to act as a X terminal. I succeed partly to do that (with Xorg -quary ...), but it is really too slow, as you said. And it's the same running single app throush "ssh -X ...". With VNC, the performance is acceptable. I give up now, we simply share the server, the remote user and me, until his machine is repaired.